# Where is the product search call in magento 1?

Tags: magento-1.9, search

I want to modify product search magento 1 , but i am not able to find the search call in magento 1 files ,
please let me know if anybody knows it or how to find it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to determine which template files to edit, is to enable the "`Template Path Hints`" in your Magento Configuration.

To do this, do the following:

In your Magento Admin, go to `System > Configuration > Developer`

On the top left under `Current Configuration Scope`, select `Main Website` (or the name of the site you are trying to modify.)

Now on the right, set `Template Path Hints` to `Yes` and click `Save Config`

Go back to your frontend. Each section will now display the exact template you need to modify. **NOTE**: You should always copy the default template files to your own template directory, instead of modifying Magento's core theme.

And i think path this :- `catalog/product/list.phtml`

most useful link :-

**https://stackoverflow.com/a/12432812/11908692**

Hope this help you

Thanks...

Comment: Thanks mohit , but i am looking for the api call for search

Comment: read two link --- 1) https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html 2) https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/Resources/Products/products.html may be help you